# Passing the value of local variable to class variable gives NullPointer when the class variable was accessed in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I get an access token as the response and try to save it in a class variable. But when i access the variable from a getter, i get null pointer exception. Here is the code snippet. 
I do not quite get the reason for this since i am assigning the value of local variable to the class variable. So even though the variable is private, I should be able to access it via any member method of the class.

```
public class Login {
private String access_token;
public String doLogin(String uName) throws Exception {
    BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
    String loginUrl = "http://www.example.com/login";
    bc.setUrl(loginUrl);
    bc.REQUEST_METHOD="POST";
    bc.CONTENT_TYPE="application/json";
    //System.out.println(url);
    System.out.println(bc.getUrl());
    bc.openConnection();
    bc.con.setDoOutput(true);
    JSONObject loginRequest = new JSONObject();
    loginRequest.put("userName", uName);
    loginRequest.put("password", "password");
    System.out.println(loginRequest);

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bc.con.getOutputStream());
    dos.writeBytes(loginRequest.toString());
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
    int responseCode = bc.con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);
    BufferedReader login = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bc.con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer loginResponse = new StringBuffer();
    while((inputLine=login.readLine())!=null){
        loginResponse.append(inputLine);
    }
    login.close();
    System.out.println("#####BEGIN LOGIN RESPONSE#####");
    System.out.println(loginResponse.toString());
    //setAccess_token(access_token);
    JSONObject jobj= new JSONObject(loginResponse.toString());
    JSONArray jArray = jobj.getJSONArray("respList");
    String access_token = jArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("ticket");
    token = jArray.toString();
    //access = new JSONObject(response);
    System.out.println("printing token"+token);
    access_token = token;
    System.out.println("printint access token"+access_token);
    return access_token;
}

public String getToken(){
    System.out.println("printing return token"+access_token);// I GET NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
    return access_token;
}
```

Comment: Look into _variable shadowing_.

Comment: "Wall of code" - that method's doing too much.  I'd bust it up into several methods that I could test independently.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
String access_token = jArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("ticket");
```

Change that line to this:

```
this.access_token = jArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("ticket");
```

Do consider refactoring.  This method's doing a lot.